# Stargazer Confidence Interval Incorrect?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, stargazer

So I am really fond of the stargazer package for displaying the statistics for regression models. I've been using R and Stata together to complete some problems in a textbook. One issue that I have found is that the confidence interval printed by the stargazer package does not correspond to the confidence interval by stata. I determined that the CI in stata is the correct one after doing it by hand.

Because the issue might may possibly lie in how I am handling the data, I offer it here as an optional choice. My primary concern is to determine why the CI's do not respond. From a previous post, here is one possible way of finding the data I am using;

```
install.packages("devtools")  # if not already installed
library(devtools)
install_git("https://github.com/ccolonescu/PoEdata")

library(PoEdata)   # loads the package in memory
library(multcomp)  # for hypo testing
data(fair4)         # loads the data set of interest
```

In Stata, the name of the dataset I am using is called `fair4.dta`. For the data itself, you can use it manually,

```
structure(list(year = structure(c(1880, 1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 
1900, 1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924, 1928, 1932, 1936, 1940, 
1944, 1948, 1952, 1956, 1960, 1964, 1968, 1972, 1976, 1980, 1984, 
1988, 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008), label = "year", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    vote = structure(c(50.2200012207031, 49.8460006713867, 50.4140014648438, 
    48.2680015563965, 47.7599983215332, 53.1710014343262, 60.0060005187988, 
    54.4830017089844, 54.7080001831055, 51.681999206543, 36.1189994812012, 
    58.2439994812012, 58.8199996948242, 40.8409996032715, 62.4580001831055, 
    54.9990005493164, 53.773998260498, 52.3699989318848, 44.5950012207031, 
    57.7639999389648, 49.9129981994629, 61.3440017700195, 49.5960006713867, 
    61.7890014648438, 48.9480018615723, 44.6969985961914, 59.1699981689453, 
    53.9020004272461, 46.5449981689453, 54.7360000610352, 50.2649993896484, 
    51.2330017089844, 46.5999984741211), label = "Incumbent share of the two-party presidential vote", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    party = structure(c(-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 
    1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
    -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1), label = "= 1 if Democratic incumbent at election time; -1 if a Republican incumbent", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    person = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 0), label = "= 1 if incumbent is running for election and 0 otherwise", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    duration = structure(c(1.75, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1.25, 0, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1.25, 0, 1, 0, 1), label = "number of terms incumbent administration in power", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    war = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), label = "= 1 for elections of 1920, 1944, and 1948 and 0 otherwise.", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    growth = structure(c(3.87899994850159, 1.58899998664856, 
    -5.55299997329712, 2.76300001144409, -10.0240001678467, -1.42499995231628, 
    -2.4210000038147, -6.2810001373291, 4.16400003433228, 2.22900009155273, 
    -11.4630002975464, -3.87199997901917, 4.6230001449585, -14.4989995956421, 
    11.7650003433228, 3.90199995040894, 4.27899980545044, 3.5789999961853, 
    0.690999984741211, -1.45099997520447, 0.377000004053116, 
    5.10900020599365, 5.04300022125244, 5.91400003433228, 3.75099992752075, 
    -3.59699988365173, 5.44000005722046, 2.17799997329712, 2.66199994087219, 
    3.12100005149841, 1.21899998188019, 2.69000005722046, 0.219999998807907
    ), label = "growth rate GDP in first three quarters of the election year", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    inflation = structure(c(1.97399997711182, 1.05499994754791, 
    0.603999972343445, 2.2739999294281, 3.41000008583069, 2.54800009727478, 
    1.44200003147125, 1.87899994850159, 2.17199993133545, 4.2519998550415, 
    0, 5.16099977493286, 0.18299999833107, 7.19999980926514, 
    2.49699997901917, 0.0810000002384186, 0, 0, 2.36199998855591, 
    1.93499994277954, 1.96700000762939, 1.25999999046326, 3.13899993896484, 
    4.81500005722046, 7.63000011444092, 7.83099985122681, 5.25899982452393, 
    2.90599989891052, 3.27999997138977, 2.06200003623962, 1.60500001907349, 
    2.32500004768372, 2.88000011444092), label = "growth rate of GDP deflator during first 15 quarters of admin", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    goodnews = structure(c(9, 2, 3, 7, 6, 7, 5, 8, 8, 3, 0, 10, 
    7, 4, 9, 8, 0, 0, 7, 5, 5, 10, 7, 4, 5, 5, 8, 4, 2, 4, 8, 
    1, 3), label = "number of quarters in first 15 with real GDP per capita growth > 3.2", format.stata = "%9.0g")), notes = c("more complete variable definitions in fair.def", 
"1"), .Names = c("year", "vote", "party", "person", "duration", 
"war", "growth", "inflation", "goodnews"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -33L))
```

So here is the stargazer code that is giving me trouble:

```
presidential <- read_dta("~/Directory/fair4.dta")
pres.lm = lm(vote ~ growth, data = subset(presidential, 
                                        presidential$year >= 1916)   
stargazer(pres.lm,
            type = "text",
            intercept.bottom = T,
            digits = 5,
            report = "vc*stp",
            ci = T
          )
confint(pres.lm, level = 0.95)
```

Consider the difference in the confidence intervals.

```
(0.52948, 1.24241)     # in R, Stargazer
0.5087671  1.263126    # in R, confint(pres.lm)
.5087671    1.263126   # in Stata
```

I also calculated by hand for the confidence intervals and the `confit()` and the Stata numbers check out. The t-critical value for this dataset should be `t_(N-2 , prob) = t(22,.0025) = -2.073873`.

In addition, I made sure to create an entirely new data frame. That is, instead of subsetting within the the `lm()` argument, I subset it first. When comparing this method to the previous one, I still get the same exact (incorrect) confidence intervals.

```
# subset into a new dataframe
presidential.1 = subset(presidential, presidential$year >= 1916)

# create the model
pres.lm.2 = lm(vote ~ growth, data = presidential.1)

# compare the two
stargazer(pres.lm,pres.lm.2,
          type = "text",
          intercept.bottom = F,
          digits = 5,
          report = "vc*stp",
          ci = T,
          t.auto = T)

                                         (1)                  (2)         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Constant                          50.84840***          50.84840***     
                              (48.86384, 52.83295) (48.86384, 52.83295)
                                  t = 50.21835         t = 50.21835    
                                  p = 0.00000          p = 0.00000     

growth                             0.88595***           0.88595***     
                               (0.52948, 1.24241)   (0.52948, 1.24241) 
                                  t = 4.87126          t = 4.87126     
                                  p = 0.00008          p = 0.00008   

# correct intervals from Stata and R's confint()
growth       0.5087671  1.263126
```

Am I running the code incorrectly? It really isn't a big deal for me to run the stargazer command and print only the coefficients and the t-stats, but it is kind of disappointing that I would have to run `confint()` as a separate command given that the output for Stargazer is gorgeous. It is quite odd because the coefficient estimates and the t-statistics are perfect. The confidence intervals are off by varying degrees, and I would like to know what the cause of this might be. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: stargazer isn't so gorgeous inside itself https://github.com/cran/stargazer/blob/master/R/stargazer-internal.R

Comment: @Hao point taken. Well relative to using the 'summary(model)', stargazer looks pretty good. I just find the default output for the summary really ugly and hard to look at. If there's something better than stargazer to neatly organize the statistics of a regression mode, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that stata and `confint` calculate confidence intervals using the t-distribution, while `stargazer`'s internal method uses the normal distribution. The result is that the former two are more conservative in their estimates and thus have wider CI compared to `stargazer`. (Well, I'm assuming with stata here, but since it gives the same results as `confint` I feel it is a safe assumption).

Looking deep into the source code for `stargazer` (line 688ff) we can find how CIs are calculated:

```
z.value <- qnorm((1 + .format.ci.level.use)/2)
coef <- .global.coefficients[.global.coefficient.variables[which.variable],i]
se <- .global.std.errors[.global.coefficient.variables[which.variable],i]
ci.lower.bound <- coef - z.value * se
ci.upper.bound <- coef + z.value * se
```

It uses `qnorm` to set the critical value.

Compare to `confint`:

```
a <- (1 - level)/2
a <- c(a, 1 - a)
fac <- qt(a, object$df.residual) ##Relevant line, uses T-distribution
pct <- format.perc(a, 3)
ci <- array(NA, dim = c(length(parm), 2L), dimnames = list(parm, 
    pct))
ses <- sqrt(diag(vcov(object)))[parm]
ci[] <- cf[parm] + ses %o% fac
```

Compare:

```
#Using normal/z distribution
> pres.lm$coefficients[2] + sqrt(diag(vcov(pres.lm)))[2] %o% c(-qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2), qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2))
            [,1]     [,2]
growth 0.5294839 1.242409

#Using t-distribution with df degrees of freedom
> df <- pres.lm$df.residual
> pres.lm$coefficients[2] + sqrt(diag(vcov(pres.lm)))[2] %o% c(-qt((1 + 0.95)/2, df), qt((1 + 0.95)/2, df))
            [,1]     [,2]
growth 0.5087671 1.263126
```

Probably the easiest way to handle this if you are committed to `stargazer` is to use the `ci.custom` argument:

```
> stargazer(pres.lm, type = "text", ci.custom = list(confint(pres.lm)))

===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                               vote            
-----------------------------------------------
growth                       0.886***          
                          (0.509, 1.263)       

Constant                     50.848***         
                         (48.749, 52.948)      

-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    24             
R2                             0.519           
Adjusted R2                    0.497           
Residual Std. Error       4.798 (df = 22)      
F Statistic           23.729*** (df = 1; 22)   
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Once the sample size is sufficiently large, the t-distribution converges on the z-distribution and the differences between the CIs become much smaller.

```
set.seed(432)

x1 <- rnorm(10000, 100, 50)
u <- 2 * rnorm(10000)
y <- 50 + x1 * 0.752 * u

fit <- lm(y ~ x1)

> confint(fit)
                  2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) 39.29108955 54.1821315
x1          -0.02782141  0.1061173
> stargazer(fit, type= "text", ci = T)

===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                                 y             
-----------------------------------------------
x1                             0.039           
                          (-0.028, 0.106)      

Constant                     46.737***         
                         (39.292, 54.181)      

-----------------------------------------------
Observations                  10,000           
R2                            0.0001           
Adjusted R2                   0.00003          
Residual Std. Error     168.194 (df = 9998)    
F Statistic            1.313 (df = 1; 9998)    
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

With a sample size of 24, the t-distribution with 22 degrees of freedom has much fatter tails than the z!

Comment: Thank you so much @paqmo . This answers my question perfectly. I'll make sure to use the 'ci.custom()' function then!